# Aquery - cache downsampled version of the image

Tags: android, android-query

I have a Custom AdapterView (sort of) in which I lazy load images. To do it, I use the awesome [aquery library](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/).

**Short story**: I would like to cache (memcache and filecache) the downsampled version of the file. It makes it quicker to add to my adapter - when the image is small I have no lags when scrolling my AdapterView. When the image is big, even if I use downsampling it lags a bit. I found out, that `aquery` stores the full version of image and downsamples it every time I call `aq.image(...)`. **How to cache the resized version**, not the original one?

---

**Long story:**
My AdapterView relies heavily on images. These images are rather big, and when adapter items gets instantiated it takes some time to downsample it and then add to the list. So I thought it would be nice, to instantiate items with a lo-res photo when scrolling, and only load the hi-res version when the scrolling stops. It works like a charm, when I use two separate image urls (one for thumnbail and another for the original image). But the API I work with is quite limited, so I won't have the thumbnail images' urls. I have to async download the big version, downsample it, save both big and small version and then use whichever I need. And here the "short story" begins.

Comment: Did you finally manage to get it work with aquery or you switched to some alternatives?

Comment: I switched originally from picasso to aquery since picasso would fail if i tried to download and show extra large images( larger the 2048px ...didnt do downsampling properly)...but i might give it a go again if you didnt have those problems...

Answer (score 2):

I just released an open source library called [droidQuery](https://github.com/phil-brown/droidQuery) which is a full port of *jQuery* to Android. It is much simpler to use than `AQuery`, and provides a lot more configurations. To download an image and set the output size, and cache the small image (on a per-session/every ten minute basis), you can use the following code:

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions(url).type("GET")
                           .dataType("image")
                           .imageHeight(200)
                           .imageWidth(200)
                           .context(this)
                           .cache(true)
                           .cacheTimeout(600000)
                           .success(new Function() {
                               @Override
                               public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                   $.with(image).val((Bitmap) params[0]);
                               }
                           })
                           .error(new Function() {
                               @Override
                               public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                   droidQuery.toast("could not set image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                               }
                           }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also used AQuery library in the past, but after encountering some problems with limited configuration and weird progresbar visibility issue, I moved to Android-Universal-Image Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader it gives you your needed feature as well as plenty other useful configuration options.

Just read this site from top to bottom - and you should be able to run it in a minute.

In your case most interesting lines are

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
    .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
    .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
    .discCacheFileCount(100)
```

You can also change cached file names.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I love the simplicity of AQuery and I hope it's possible to do it with that lib, but I read the source for two hours and can't find anything... Maybe AUIL will suit me better

Comment: Unfortunately this: `memoryCacheExtraOptions(50, 50)` can only be set in the `init` phase. I can't set the thumbnails size in per-file basis. Plus, it doesn't seem to use my settings. I set it to (50, 50), but the bitmap is still hi-res.